# Site wide search on a rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, search, plugins

I'm trying to add search capability to one of my rails applications.  I just need it to search through the mysql columns of quite a few models well.  I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.  I figure I should use a plugin but I don't see anyone really recommending one over another.  Is there one you would recommend over all others?  How is acts_as_ferret? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/tree/master) might be worth checking out. Mr ryanb just did an [awesome railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/176-searchlogic) on it. If you're looking for a fulltext solution, he also has a [screencast on Thinking Sphinx](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx).

Comment: I use Sphinx for this. It's pretty clean to implement - I've got 20 lines of Ruby code that uses the Riddle client (from the thinking_sphinx guy). There is one catch - Sphinx needs a unique document ID for each thing that you index. I use sql_query_pre, sql_query_post and a @variable to make sure that each document gets a unique ID (that I ignore completely).

Comment: Searchlogic is great, but I don't believe is offers any cross-model search capabilities. (Correct me if I'm wrong!)

Sphinx and ThinkingSphinx certainly do, though, and very effectively in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `acts_as_ferret`.  Here's something you could do.  Create a table like so:

```
create_table(:indexed_models) do |t|
  t.column :name, :string
  t.column :model_id, :id
  t.column :index, :string
end
```

For each model you want to search on, concatenate the values from the searchable columns to create an "index".  Insert the results in to the indexed_models table.  Where the name is the model's name, model_id is it's primary key, and index is the searchable content.  Use observers to create and update the indexed_models table when the models you've designated as "searchable" change.

Do a text search of the index field of indexed_models, then generate a container of models based on the return model name & primary key.

I've never used this approach either, but I've been meaning too.

Comment: Just a thought: If you're going to go down that route, you could use a polymorphic relationship between the indexed model and its original model - ActiveRecord would then give you a method of getting from the indexed model to the original without you needing to roll your own.

Comment: @NeilS  Good point, use STI (Single Table Inheritance) for all these searchable models.  That way, the "name" column of create_table is not necessary.  If you've already got models, or can't make STI work for these models, then it's a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend **Sphinx** as a search daemon and indexer. It's really good, customizable and scalable.

As a client and front-end library use **UltraSphinx** or **ThinkingSphinx** . The second has a better support recently.

Comment: Is ThinkingSphinx able to search files like PDF?